# Bing Maps V8 Web Control: Make autosuggest dropdown select first suggestion by default

Tags: javascript, web, bing-maps, bing, autosuggest

Short summary:

I have a question around the Autosuggest Module of the JavaScript Map Control API. I see in the example ( https://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdk/mapcontrol/isdk/autosuggestui#JS ) that the autosuggest dropdown does not by default select the first suggestion. Instead, a user must mouse over and click the suggestion or arrow down to select it and then hit enter. I am trying to have the first item in the dropdown be autoselected so that the user only needs to type the initial part of their address and then hit enter once they see the autosuggestion come up.

Full explanation:

The codebase that I am working in already has a workaround solution to this where it handles the keypress event and then uses the getSuggestions() function ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/v8-web-control/modules/autosuggest-module/autosuggestmanager-class ). However, this has some drawbacks:

1. The first item in the displayed autosuggestions is not highlighted, so there’s no visual indication to the user that hitting ENTER would select this first item.
2. Because the getSuggestions() function is called out of band of the input box and suggestions container, it is difficult to be sure that the first item in the displayed autosuggestions will be selected by getSuggestions(), and it would be difficult to know if this eventually stopped working (because of some update for example).
3. The callback for the getSuggestions() function returns a SuggestionResult[], and these do not have defined geographical coordinates in them, whereas the callback for attachAutosuggest does have geocoordinates. This is surmountable via using a REST api call to bing maps to get the coordinates, but it does make things much more complicated.
4. The code for this has to be a little bit complicated because in the case that the ENTER keypress event was already handled by Bing Maps event handlers (because the user did an arrow down and then hit enter), we then need to not re-handle the event ourselves. The code for doing this is fragile.

Answer (score 1):

The solution here is to use custom UI components to create the dropdown menu and then use Bing Maps' REST API to fill in the data. This requires a good bit of work to get right, but once completed you would have complete control over how the interface was presented to users.